# One property with a list of model errors in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my controller which is having a list (atmost 3) error messages related to password check will be stored in the property named Password.

```
IEnumerable<PasswordMessages> passwordMessage = LoanTrackerServices.CheckPasswordRequirements(model.NewPassword, model.EmailId);
if ( passwordMessage.Count() > 0 )
{
    foreach (PasswordMessages pm in passwordMessage)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password",( pm.Message));
    }
    LoginPageModel loginModel = new LoginPageModel();
    return View("Index", new HomePageModel() { Register = model, Login = loginModel });
}
```

But in my view i am unable to figure out how to get all those (atmost 3) error messages. Right now only the first message with in the list is displaying. here is my code in view

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewData.ModelState["Password"].Errors.Count; i++)
{
     @Html.ValidationMessage("Password")
}
```

How to get all those error messages which are stored with in the Password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a summary instead of a message:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("Password")
```

So get rid of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewData.ModelState["Password"].Errors.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Password")
}
```

Comment: This one works. but it is displaying heading before the messages

Comment: @user2619542, you can modify the template. Just look at the HTML/CSS that's rendered and target the rendered tags. To get rid of the heading, target the tag and set `display: none`.

Comment: I used the style display:none, then it is not at all displaying the error messages. I want those error messages just without the heading message

Comment: @user2619542, if you target the right element it won't hide the entire set of messages; your CSS is just wrong. Target the heading, the element you want to get rid of, specifically.

Comment: these are the styles in CSS .validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
  display:none;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
i added display:non for validation-summary-errors class

Comment: @user2619542, you're going to have to target the element that displays the heading inside of `validation-summary-errors`. Targeting `validation-summary-errors` is targeting the entire `div`. It's probably an `h1`. Again, ***target the element that contains the text of the heading, not the entire `div`.***

Comment: Is there any other way like by using inline styles rather than changing the default CSS style, because other people also can use them. If there is any inline style, then i can change there it self

Comment: @user2619542, you'd have to build your own `ValidationSummary` method, that's the only other alternative.

Comment: do you have any other idea other than using validationsummary. because i am using partial views and if i using the validation summary it displaying error messages in all partial views. So i removed validationsummary and replaced with ValidationMessageFor for all the model errors. So in that case i created my own UnorderedList with in the DIV

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Will show all Model errors in one place what isn't desirable for the most cases.

I've written a helper method which will let you show only errors for specific field: https://gist.github.com/DimaSalakhov/8548393. It's based on standart `ValidationMessageFor<>()`.

Add it to your project, referrence on a View and use as follows:

```
@Html.ValidationSummaryFor(x => x.Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(nameof(Model.Property)))
{
     // show some thing
}
else
{
     // show some thing else
}
```

**Strongly typed validation check .**